# what are the sequence of events that happen when you get a page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, get

Im trying to get my head around the sequence of events that happen between when rails receives a get/post command and the page is served. I was just trying to map out the sequence myself and i realised i dont fully understand myself which scripts is even ran first so I'd like to clear it up in my head.

many thanks

jon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The request goes into the route matcher which parses the URL, parses the config/routes.rb and if the URL matches a route, it looks for a controller file whose name matches the controller part of the URL, (e.g. http://localhost/categories will look for a CategoriesController)

Then, one of two things happen:

1. If you're using a Rails restful route, the route matcher applies heuristics to figure out which of the 7 actions to call: a GET on a plural last part is mapped to index; a GET mapped to an ID-looking part after the plural is mapped to show (e.g. categories/1 or categories/something or categories/1-something); a POST to a plural last part is mapped to create; a PUT to an ID-looking part after the plural is mapped to update; a DELETE to the same URL is mapped to destroy; new and edit are mapped to GETs for categories/new & categories/edit.

   1. If you have a custom action, you must have a method in your controller object of the same name.

The chosen action is executed and then Rails either renders the template/file/action specified in the render call within the action or it looks for a view file of the same name as the action and that ends with .html.erb (by default) in the app/views/ directory.

Simple.

Comment: ok so (to greatly simplify im sure :) of the model, view and controller files the controller is the first called which then calls the model files to modify the database and/or calls the view files which render the content to be served to the client

Comment: Yep, :). Sorry, I thought you wanted something more detailed than that.

Answer (score 2):

Rails does quite a lot of things, a good way to get a decent overview is to read the "Action Controller Overview" document at rails guides: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html

The basic structure is:

1. rack middleware
2. routing
3. filters
4. controller code
5. rendering
6. filters

But rails also does many things by itself to the request. It automatically determines what kind of response you want based on your accept headers, and/or if you manually specify which type of response you want with a file ending like /blog/1.xml. Rails also magically creates a nicely formatted params hash, parsing params like user[name]=foo to {:user => {:name => "foo"}}. Rails also has built-in exception handling and some nice stuff to prevent cross site request forgery and much more, so check out the Controller Overview for the lowdown on that.